# Add banner to corner of wordpress with css

Tags: css, wordpress, banner

How can I add a banner to the corner of a wordpress post using css or within the post itself. I've attacked a screen of what I'd like it to look like, but I don't know how to get it done.

[image]

Comment: Why would you down check this question?

Comment: Users most often downvote questions because the feel that they don't adequately meet the criteria of http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions. They may also feel that the question "does not show any research effort."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a background image to your post class and set the `background-position` property to `top right`

```
.post {background:url('your-image.jpg') top right no-repeat}
```

Comment: Then to add background color just do background: #ffffff url('blah") right?

Comment: You've got it!  That's the shorthand way to do it but alternatively you could declare each property separately.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the parent div has position: relative (or position: absolute) set, then set your banner to position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;

Comment: Thanks for your input, why would anyone down check this question.